# How can i set "only" restriction properly in protege?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I want to represent in Protégé a container of balls. I have a RedBallContainer class that is a Container and a RedBall that is a Ball, like in this figure:

[image: class hierarchy]

I have created a property Contains that has domain Container and Range Ball.

Now I wanted to say "a container is a RedBallContainer if only contains red balls". To do this I added the following rule:

[image: rule]

Now, when I run the reasoner, it says me that the Container class is equals to Thing, but I think it is wrong for what I wanted to represent! Here there is a picture of what the reasoner infers:

[image: reasoner result]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh one other thing: if you click that little question mark to the right of any inferred fact, the reasoner will calculate an explanation. The output can be a bit cryptic sometimes but it may be useful to determine _why_ a particular fact was inferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your restriction rule is incorrect. It says

"RedballContainer is equivalent to a class that *only* contains RedBallContainers"

It should be:

"RedballContainer is equivalent to a class that *only* contains RedBalls"

**Edit** as you found out the above fix does not remove the strange inferred equivalence relation. The reason it's there is somewhat convoluted, but it's roughly this:

1. we know that the domain of `contains` is `Container`, so anything that uses a `contains` property is, by definition, a `Container`.
2. we know that `RedBallContainer` is equivalent to anything that contains only `RedBall`s, so any item that contains only red balls is a red ball container.
3. we also know that `RedBallContainer` is a subclass of `Container`.

Now imagine some item that is not a `Container`. Two options are possible: it either contains something, or nothing. If it does contain something, by definition 1 it still is a `Container` after all.

However, if it does *not* contain anything, that means that all the balls it contains are in fact red balls (because none of the zero balls it contains are not red balls)! By our second definition, this thing therefore is a `RedBallContainer`. By our third definition, it therefore must be a `Container` after all.

In short, under this set of rules it's not possible for something to not be a `Container`. Everything is a `Container`, so `Container` and `Thing` are equivalent.

Ah, logic.

To fix, you could change your restriction to say that a `RedBallContainer` is equivalent to any `Container` that only contains red balls:

```
   EquivalentTo Container and contains only RedBall
```

Comment: I realized 10 minutes after asking, I apologize for the oversight. Anyway with 
Contains only RedBalls the error is still here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explaination, I tried what you suggested and it works!